# Find $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi]$ such that $z=5+9i$

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I am having difficulty understanding how to be within the bound for my theta. I got $\theta = 60.9453$ (first quadrant), but it needs to be between -$\pi$ and $\pi$. If I am thinking of the unit circle, then doesn't my $\theta$; need to be either in either the 3rd or 4th quadrant, so wouldn't I need to subtract $\pi$?

[image]

Edit: I forgot that we were working in radians and not degrees. A simple mistake. But I still get confused on when I need to add or subtract by $\pi$. For example, I need to find $\theta$ for z= -3+6i. I understand tan^(-1)(6/-3)= -1.1071, but why do I need to add $\pi$ since -1.1071 is between -3.14 and 3.14?

Comment: (5,9) is in the first quadrant.

Comment: change to radian and your $\theta $ will be within bounds.

Comment: Radians... not degrees....  $(-\pi, \pi]$ is the range of a full circle.

Comment: It looks like you're interacting with some software that automatically decides whether what you wrote in each box is correct or incorrect. If the green outline means "correct" then the software must recognize `sqrt` as the square root function. Perhaps it does not recognize `tan^(-1)` as the inverse tangent. You might need to write the name of the function differently. Is there any documentation that says what function names the software recognizes?

Comment: I did not have my calculator set to radians, but even so, I am still getting some of the thetas wrong...

Comment: $60.9^o$ looks ok for tan$=1.8$.  What's your problem?

Comment: @herbsteinberg see my answer.

Comment: "some of the thetas"? You have shown only one number that needs a $\theta.$ We cannot read your mind to see what it is that you  are doing and not telling us that is causing you trouble. Try editing the question, carefully, beginning at the beginning and showing every step you took and every number you wrote down, always explaining why you did what you did, until something went wrong that you would like to see explained. Then maybe someone will see the source of your confusion and be able to explain it.

Comment: @user2661923  The only problem I see is his confusion between radians and degrees.  The answer is correct for degrees.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I disagree with your last comment, because the range of the answer, $(-\pi, \pi]$ is a range of dimensionless real numbers.  So, the problem composer intends that the answer not be any type of angle, because angles are not dimensionless.  As I stated in my answer + subsequent comments, it seems as if the OP is untrained in considering the domain of trig functions as dimensionless numbers.  So, I think the problem is the conflict between trig functions whose domain are angles and trig functions whose domain are dimensionless numbers.  ...see next comment

Comment: @herbsteinberg I infer that when you refer to the confusion between radians and degrees, you are using radians as a unit of measure of angles.  If you presume that this is the intent of the problem composer, you run into the conflict that the problem was poorly worded, and should have specified that $-\pi$ radians $< \theta \leq \pi$ radians.

Comment: It looks like nitpicking.  When talking about angles in radians as arguments for trig. function, the word radian usually doesn't have to be said.  Saying an angle $=\pi$ is sufficient.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Agreed, based on your perspective and (arguably) the perspective of the problem composer.  However, given the first two sentences in the question presented by the original poster (i.e. the OP) it is plausible in my mind that the OP's confusion would have been avoided if the *radians* unit of measure had been included.

Comment: The edit asks a question different from the one that is answered below. But a counterquestion: instead of $-1.1071$ or $-1.1071+\pi,$ why shouldn't the answer be $1.1071$? or even $-2$? After all, all of those numbers are between $-\pi$ and $\pi,$ so they're all good, right?

Comment: Now for a hint why it must be $-1.1071+\pi$ and not any of those other numbers: the complex number $-3+6i$ is in the second quadrant, and $-1.1071+\pi$ gives you a $\theta$ in the second quadrant. The other $\theta$ values are all in other quadrants so they cannot possibly be correct for $-3+6i.$ For example, if $r=3\sqrt5$ and $\theta=\tan^{-1}(6/-3)\approx-1.1071,$ then $re^{i\theta} = 3 - 6i,$ not $-3 + 6i.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what is being overlooked is that as a math student transitions between Analytical Geometry and Real Analysis (AKA Calculus), there is a great deal of confusion about what a radian is.  There is also confusion about  whether the domain of trig functions such as the sine, cosine, and tangent functions are **dimensionless** real numbers, or angles.

All angles are associated with a unit of measure, such as a degree or a radian.  Here, $360^\circ = 360~$ degrees = $2\pi$ radians.

However, the OP (i.e. original poster) is (**very reasonably**) interpreting the stated problem, as asking for an angle that is a dimensionless Real Number in the range $(-\pi, \pi].$

The problem stated that $\theta$ must be in the range $(-\pi, \pi].$  However, this is a range of dimensionless Real Numbers.  On the other hand, the OP has probably never been trained in how to treat $\theta$ as anything other than an angle.

---

Resolution:

In beginning Calculus, where this problem is intended to be attacked, it is to be understood that $(-\pi, \pi]$ refers to $(-\pi ~\text{radians}, \pi ~\text{radians}]$, so that what is being asked for is a dimensioned angle.

The answer that the OP derived is **not** 
$\theta = 60.9453$ 
but rather 
$\theta = 60.9453~$ degrees.

The OP didn't understand that the problem was poorly written, and was asking for an angle whose unit of measure is radians, rather than degrees.  With this understanding, then the OP learns that he has to apply a conversion ratio similar to converting $3$ feet into $1$ yard : $360$ degrees equals $(2\pi)$ radians.

---

This begs the question : why was this problem poorly worded.  It is because the consideration of a radian as a unit of measure for an angle is a *beginning Calculus* crutch that is necessarily eradicated as the student studies Calculus more deeply.

Then, the domain of trig functions become dimensionless Real Numbers, rather than dimensioned angles.  Here, the term *Radian* stops being used to refer to a unit of measure to be applied to angles.

Instead, the term *Radian* starts being used to refer to the **dimensionless** ratio of the arc length of a portion  of the arc of a unit circle (of radius $= 1$), as compared to one complete revolution of the unit circle.  The arc length of one complete revolution is $2\pi$, when the radius is $1$.

This is often referred to as $2\pi$ radians.  Here, the term radian is simply the dimensionless proportion of arc length to a complete revolution.  Thus, (for example) since a $45$ degree angle creates an arc whose length is $(1/8)$ of a complete revolution, the corresponding **dimensionless** arc length is referred to as $\pi/4$ or $\pi/4$ radians.

Comment: "Use an angle in $(-\pi,\pi]$" looks like dimensionless real numbers to me. No "radians" are mentioned. For all we know, of course, this way of thinking may have been sprung upon the hapless student with no transition from the old "radians crutch." Or it may be that this exercise comes after an extensive discussion of the "beginner's" trig functions versus the pure math functions that the student is now supposed to use. The fact that OP thinks of subtracting $\pi$ (rather than "$\pi$ radians") to change quadrants suggests that the word "radians" (or lack thereof) is not the stumbling block.

Comment: @DavidK Reasonable rebuttal that I disagree with.  For me, the compelling issue is the OP's confusion about what $60.9453$ represents.  It must represent $60.9453$ degrees.  Also, this is a *beginning* Calculus problem.  I infer from this that the OP is presuming that the domain of trig functions are angles.  Otherwise, he would have understood that $60.9453$ is a nonsensical answer.  Once you infer that the OP thought that $60.9453$ was not a nonsensical answer, my response seems like the probable explanation for the OP's confusion.

Comment: As noted in a comment, "I did not have my calculator set to radians ... ." This is one reason I think OP is aware (now) that the $60.9453$ is in degrees. And yet still confused somehow. I think there is also another educational issue here, the blind reliance on a calculator with no mental check on the answer to clue the student in when he has failed to push the correct buttons. Even a precalculus student should recognize that when the arc tangent comes out to $60$ you have obviously left the calculator set to degrees.

Comment: Yet I do not have any better ability than you (maybe not even as good) to read OP's mind, so it may be that I am guessing incorrectly.

Comment: @DavidK You say tomAto, I say tomato.  The fact that the calculator goes back and forth between degrees and radians reinforces the intuition that the domain of trig functions are angles (in the world of Calculators).

Comment: @DavidK Actually, my perspective is biased by my experiences on mathSE with other students being confused about the domain of trig functions.  Further, this issue also originally confused me.  Therefore, my pre-judgement is that this concept is almost universally confusing to the beginning Calculus student.

Comment: @DavidK I have edited my post to include my confusion for another question so it makes better sense of what I was commenting